# Unity: enemy spawner behavior

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

Im working on a game and i just cant figure out how to fix my enemy spawner. Im aiming for a certain behavior which is spawning easy enemies x20( or any no.) then medium enemies and after that a endless spawn of random  easy, medium and hard enemies . I also want between each spawn to have like a delay or break for 1-2 seconds so it doesn't looks like the enemies are spamming on top of each other

Currently i'm having only easy and medium enemies to spawn and its ending its not endless besides im getting an array out of range error

Your help is appreciated and thank you in advance 
This is my Code:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine.UI;

  public class Test : MonoBehaviour
  {

   public GameObject[] enemy; 

   public Transform[] spawnPoints;         

   private float timer = 2;


   int index = 0 ;

   int wave = 0;

   List <GameObject> EnemiesList = new           List<GameObject>();

  private int enemyCount=20;


  void Update()
 {
  timer -= Time.deltaTime;

if (timer <= 0 && wave < 6)
{
    timer = 3;

    if (wave != 0 &&  wave % 2 == 0)
    {
        index ++ ;
    }

    EnemySpawner();

    wave++;
}

}

 void Spawn ()
 {

for (int i = 0; i<enemyCount;i++)
{
    Invoke("EnemySpawner" , i + 2);
}
}

void EnemySpawner ()
 {
int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length);

GameObject InstanceEnemies= Instantiate ( enemy[index] , spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position , spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation) as GameObject;

EnemiesList.Add(InstanceEnemies);

 }



}
```

Comment: what does this mean:  "Its. Lt endless "  You may have to click Edit to clarify.

Comment: @JoeBlow edit. Sorry